# How to get spectral data of Sun?

Tags: astrophysics, thermal-radiation, data

I am doing project in blackbody radiation and i am about to analyse the spectral data of the incandescent lamp, hot metal, Sun and Sirius A. So i can find the displacement of the peak of curves using Wien's displacement I don't have the required apparatus to obtain the data but i heard that i can get such data from internet. So i searched. But unfortunately I am noob at this so i couldn't get any data. If anyone know anything about it please help me to get the data

Comment: **Do NOT attempt to measure the spectrum of the Sun unless you use the correct equipment and have had the arrangement certified as being safe.**  It is best to rely on published data.

Comment: I strongly support the above comment. The only way that you can try and get a safe spectrum of the sun by yourself is on a cloudy day by only observing the light scattered off the terrestrial clouds.

Comment: I need that published data. Can you give me that link to access it

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a spectrometer, which can be made out of pieces of cardboard and a strip of clear plastic film with tiny scratches in it called a *diffraction grating*. There are cheap do-it-yourself spectrometer kits available on-line for students to build their own spectrometers in the classroom, and they come with instructions on how to use them and what sorts of experiments you can do with them.

Spectrometers can be connected to telescopes, so you can get spectral lines from stars, and to cameras, so you can take pictures for later study of the spectra that the diffraction grating produces.

Google on "homemade spectrometer", or "DIY spectrometer kit".

Comment: Or here you can find the data, at the bottom you can download it. https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/appendices/standard-solar-spectra

Answer (score 0):

You may buy a diffraction grating for telescopic use, look for Star Analyzer. They can be placed in front of a telephoto lens and gives spectra of the sun and stars. For the sun it may be necessary to dampen the light.